# Transfer onclick functionality from element to button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

This code changes the colour of the elements in a svg (guitar strings) when those elements are clicked, and ensures all other strings that weren't clicked revert to or remain the default colour (class1).

```
<style> 
.class1{ stroke:#adad8b; }
.class2{ stroke:#000000; }
</style> 

<svg>
<g> 
<path class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)" id="e-string" fill="none" stroke-width="2" d="M502.583,13.046v411.966" />
<path class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)" id="b-string" fill="none" stroke-width="2.5" d="M472.366,13.046v411.966"/>
<path class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)" id="g-string" fill="none" stroke-width="3" d="M440.134,13.046v411.966"/>
<path class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)" id="d-string" fill="none" stroke-width="3.3" d="M405.887,13.046v411.966"/>
<path class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)" id="a-string" fill="none" stroke-width="3.5" d="M373.655,13.042v411.965"/>
<path class="class1" onclick="toggleClass(this)" id="e-low" fill="none" stroke-width="4" d="M341.423,13.046v411.966"/>
</g>
</svg>

<script>
function toggleClass(el) {
  // Get the parent element of the clicked string, and then its first child element
  var kid = el.parentElement.firstElementChild;
  // Loop through all the child elements
  while (kid != null) {
    // Set theis child's class
    kid.setAttribute("class", "class1");
    // Get the next child
    kid = kid.nextElementSibling;
  }
  // Set the new class on the clicked element
  el.setAttribute("class", "class2");
}
</script>
```

I'd now like to add six buttons to the page which target the guitar strings, so that the same functionlity exists, but the user is required to press the corresponding button, not the guitar string itself. So for example, the buttons would be added to the page like so:

```
<button type="button">E-String</button>
<button type="button">B-String</button>
<button type="button">G-String</button>
<button type="button">D-String</button>
<button type="button">A-String</button>
<button type="button">E-Low</button>
```

How do I add the toggleClass function so that the functionality that currently exists when clicking on the string directly, is transferred to the button? i.e. when a button is clicked, the corresponding string changes colour, and all other strings stay the default colour.

I've tried something like this where I try and target the string id but it doesn't do anything.

```
<button type="button" onclick="toggleClass(e-string)" >E-String</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The first thing you need to know is that we can not change the color the HTML button element with the 'stroke'. You should use the 'background-color' property for buttons**

You can use Jquery to do it easily

**I created two css style to change the color: the btn-class1 and the btn-class2**

```js
/*Javascript code */

$('.class1').on('click', function (){
  $('.class1 ').attr('class', 'class1');
  $(this).attr("class", 'class2');
});
 
$("button").on("click", function (){
  $('button').attr('class', 'btn-class1');
  $(this).attr("class", 'btn-class2');
 });
```

```css
/* Css style for svg */
.class1{ stroke:#adad8b; }
.class2{ stroke:#000000; }

/*css style for buttons */
.btn-class1 { background-color: #adad8b; }
.btn-class2 { background-color: #000000;color:white }
```

```html
<!-- I presume you have included Jquery like this -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg>
<g> 
<path class="class1"  id="e-string" fill="none" stroke-width="2" d="M502.583,13.046v411.966" />
<path class="class1"  id="b-string" fill="none" stroke-width="2.5" d="M472.366,13.046v411.966"/>
<path class="class1"  id="g-string" fill="none" stroke-width="3" d="M440.134,13.046v411.966"/>
<path class="class1"  id="d-string" fill="none" stroke-width="3.3" d="M405.887,13.046v411.966"/>
<path class="class1"  id="a-string" fill="none" stroke-width="3.5" d="M373.655,13.042v411.965"/>
<path class="class1"  id="e-low" fill="none" stroke-width="4" d="M341.423,13.046v411.966"/>
</g>
</svg>

<button type="button">E-String</button>
<button type="button">B-String</button>
<button type="button">G-String</button>
<button type="button">D-String</button>
<button type="button">A-String</button>
<button type="button">E-Low</button>
```